# Objective C: How to add spinner to navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, spinner

I have an issue of locking my screen whenever I try to refresh my page.

How can I load data from the server and add a spinner to the navigation bar (like instagram) without locking my screen?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add spinner you can do something like

```
    UIActivityIndicatorView *ai = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:ai] autorelease]; 
   [ai startAnimating];
   [ai release];
```

What about locking? I didn't understand.

Comment: he means asynchronously download the data from the server while not blocking the user interface from spinning

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at this [open source project](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD#readme) for what you need, several examples are there for you to consult.

> The MBProgressHUD displays a translucent HUD with a progress indicator
>   and some optional labels while work is being done in a background
>   thread

Answer (score 0):

As for not blocking the UI, have a look at [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1).  The basics are fairly easy to implement.  Specifically, have a look at `dispatch_async()` and `dispatch_sync()`;